# Serializing Dictionary via DataContractSerializer in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, dictionary, datacontractserializer

When I try to serialize IDictionary implementation I get NotImplementedException (in .NET is OK)

```
[DataMember]
public Dictionary<string, string> CustomAttributes;
```

I can not find information about Dicitionary serializing in SL and why I can not do this. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Well,

Dictionary is not Serializable via DataContractSerializer.

You can check [SerializableDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg496181.aspx)

or you can serialize it to JSON if its your case via ServiceStack or JSON.NET. Both can serialize Dictionary out of the box.

Comment: May be some ideas why this is was not implemented?